# Setting access permissions to enclosed files for a NAS

Tags: permissions, mount, backup, sync

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 Lts and a NAS (Synology, but I don't think the brand is relevant to my issue) where I backup my data and shares synced files with others. 
My NAS synced files and folders from two different locations in my computer:

- home : /home (my default hdd in ubuntu)
- Data : /media/'myusername'/Data : which is a mounted hdd on which I store
  data.

Everytime I reboot my computer the syncing software has trouble because it does not have sufficient access permission to sync files in Data (There is no issue to access home).

So I went to change permission (in property of Data) to give Create and Delete permissions to others. It worked until I reboot my computer. Then, the "not sufficient access permission" came back. I went back to the permission setting, the "Create and Delete permissions to others" was already activated, however, I had this time to change in "Change permissions for enclosed files" "Others : Read & Write + Create and delete files". And I have to do this every time I reboot my computer.

I have two related questions:

- how can I give access to this syncing software so that I don't have to change manually permission every time ?
- is there a more secure way to do it than giving all access and permission to "others" ? (I don't know why, but I feel there should be a way to say I only give these permission to the syncing software (Synology cloud station rather than every other users)

Thank you !

Comment: What syncing software is it, and how is it configured? How are you mounting `Data`? Probably you need to mount it as root (via /etc/fstab) and run the sync as root.

Comment: @steeldriver: thesoftware is synology cloud station drive. How can I run it "as root" ? I already configure it to run at start-up.  Data is mounted at startup as well. In mount station I have a form where it shows 'nosuid, nodev, nofail, x-gfvs-show'. I don't know whether it replies to you questions...